# Android Deeplink Website Association Keystore Password Issue

Tags: android, android-deep-link

I am trying to add my website to my app for deeplink, but when I try to generate digital asset links file using my release keystore file, getting the following error.

[image: generate digital asset links file]

I know that this keystore file has a password, but there is no option to enter the password in this page. Where can I enter the password?